# Laravel: Editing one-to-many relationship fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table structure similar to this:

```
id   name   superpower
 1     A      speed
 2     A      stamina
 3     B      speed
 4     C      power
 5     B      power
 6     D      sarcasm
```

Name has a one-to-many relationship to Superpower. To edit these fields, the front-end form returns an array of superpowers for the name. I.e., the 'edit A' form could return `['speed','power']` (removing stamina and adding power).

An easy way to do this with pure PHP is to remove all superpowers of the name and add the new ones. What is the best way to do this in Laravel?

Comment: You might look into Laravel relationships' sync method.

Comment: Are there the "name" and "superpower" are a relation to an entity?

Comment: Thanks @GoogleMac, I'll look into it. 
Mesuti - I don't understand the question clearly, but there is a User model for auth, then a Kid model for the details of the kids, then Superpower model for the details of the superpowers, and Kid and Superpower interact in this table that links the kids to their superpowers (one to many).

Comment: @GoogleMac Do you want to post it as a more comprehensive answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a User model (for auth), a Kid model for the details of the kids, and then Superpower model for the details of the superpowers.

You have two options that I see. Option one requires a bigger structural change, but easier controller logic while the other is heavier in the controller.

## 1 -

Create a many-to-many relationship with the kids and superpowers. This may not fit your use case if the users can add new superpowers that are viewable to all other users. This would involve a pivot table that would store each connection between a kid and a superpower.

When returning an array of superpowers to link to a kid (let's say a checkbox list is being submitted in a form), you can use the relationships' `sync` method:

```
$kid->superpowers->sync($superpowers);
```

## 2 -

If you want to keep your relationships basically how they are, I recommend at least changing the table structure you proposed in your question so that the `name` field is `kid_id`. This would be more standard so that a kid would have a hasMany relationship to superpowers and a superpower would have a belongsTo with a kid.

Then you could call:

```
foreach ($request->superpowers as $superpower) {
    $superpowers[] = ['superpower' => $superpower];
}

$kid->superpowers->delete();
$kid->superpowers->createMany($superpowers);
```

A noticable downside to this approach is that the data is being removed first in order to sync. The resulting `created_at` timestamps would then be incorrect.

Comment: I went with the first one, with an intermediary table. Once the relationships are set correctly, it is a matter of one line to access everything needed.